# Replace and Replace all c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am having a problem replacing the text that been found. Here my code tried so far for replace and can't seem to get it working. I know I need to use insert method but unsure what to put in there.

Here my code so far:

```
RichTextBox frm1TB = ((Form1)this.Owner).txtDisplay;

foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(replacingRichText.Text);

if (foundAt == -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
}
else
{
    frm1TB.Text = frm1TB.Text.Replace(searchText.Text, replacingRichText.Text);
    frm1TB.Text.Insert();
    frm1TB.SelectionStart = foundAt;
    frm1TB.SelectionLength = searchText.TextLength;
}
```

i got 1 richtextbox on form1 and then 2 text boxes on form 2 1form to find and findnext which is called searchText and 2 box to replace and replace next called replacingRIchText.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to replace these string in reverse order, since once you replace a string, your indexes and lengths are going to be different.

Also, for your code, I think you need to change it to something like this:

```
//frm1TB.Text = frm1TB.Text.Replace(searchText.Text, replacingRichText.Text);
//frm1TB.Text.Insert();

frm1TB.SelectionStart = foundAt;
frm1TB.SelectionLength = searchText.TextLength;
frm1TB.SelectedText = replacingRichText.Text;
```

Here is a simple example (refactor as needed):

```
private void ReplaceText(string findText, string replaceText) {
  int index = frm1TB.Text.Length - 1;
  index = frm1TB.Text.LastIndexOf(findText, index);
  while (index > -1) {
    frm1TB.SelectionStart = index;
    frm1TB.SelectionLength = findText.Length;
    frm1TB.SelectedText = replaceText;
    index = frm1TB.Text.LastIndexOf(findText, index);
  }
}
```

Comment: {
            RichTextBox frm1TB = ((Form1)this.Owner).txtDisplay;

            foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(searchText.Text);

            if (foundAt == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                frm1TB.Text = frm1TB.Text.Replace(searchText.Text, replacingRichText.Text);
                frm1TB.SelectionStart = foundAt;
                frm1TB.SelectionLength = searchText.TextLength;
            }

Comment: @Stefan I'm not sure what you want me to do with that comment.  Can you explain?